# Statistics refresh rate

Tags: achievements, ingress

In which rate are the statistics being refreshed?
Do all of the stats refresh at the same rate?

I'm observing that statistics don't refresh in fixed periods and different stats have different refresh periods. Did you observe the same thing, too? If not, does anyone know the exact rates and stat refresh types/modes?

Update:

I'm particularly talking about the Agent statistics but of course the Team and ranking stats are related to my question, too.

What I'm observing is that stats like XM recharge, XM collect, walking distance are pretty frequently refreshed (in about 5-15 mins) but stats like hack count, unique count, link count etc don't seem to be regularly refreshed. Sometimes they are updated instantly and sometimes it takes hours.

Comment: The refresh rate on Guardian appears to be less than daily, at least for when it shows up on our stats. I haven't seen any official word on it, though.

Comment: Refresh rate on my Guardian badge updates at least daily.  My scanner device is a HTC One.  Less than an hour after the daily anniversary the day ticks over on portal time held.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no unique rule but multiple rules :

- Regional and Global statistics for the MU counts refresh every 5 hours
- Guardian statistics are refreshed every day at 00h00 (it looks like 00h00 in local hour)
- other statistics are refreshed every X minutes (where 1 < X < 5 in general). You can clearly notice it when receiving a new badge, sometimes you're notified just after the action, sometimes it takes a few minutes to be notified.

BUT, sometimes, Niantic's servers have some problems and refresh rate can be totally erratic.

Comment: I think that those server problems are the root of my problem but I can't be sure about my observations. I've updated my question. I'll try to take more frequent screenshots to make a case for it. Anyway, I think your answer will be the most accurate one because Niantic never reveals such details.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [official Google Ingress support FAQ](https://support.google.com/ingress/answer/3403340?hl=en&ref_topic=3403241), it should happen within 15 minutes:

> **Q:** How often do my recharge stats update?
>   **A:** You should see your recharge activity reflected in your stats within 15 minutes.